# Cut a file in multiple files (Java)

Tags: java, split, apache-camel, bufferedreader

I need your help.
I use Talend ESB and I want to make java beans.

For example, I have this flat file:

```
11886 1855 0000004309000
11886 1855 0000057370000
11886 1856 0000057374001    
11886 1856 0000057375000
```

In my example I want 2 files (messages), a filter of "1855" and "1856" (It's the number of orders).

First file:

```
11886 1855 0000004309000
11886 1855 0000057370000
```

Second file:

```
11886 1856 0000057374001     
11886 1856 0000057375000
```

EDIT:
But I don't know the number of orders per file.

If i have three orders (three lines each) in my original file ==> I want three files with the 3 lines of each order.

If i have four orders in my original file ==> I want four files.

If i have five orders in my original file ==> I want five files.

and so on
.......................

---

This is my start code.
I would like to split in multiple file.
I'm really stuck on how to do this.

```
package beans;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.ByteArrayInputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.LinkedHashMap;
import java.util.Map;
import org.apache.camel.*;


public class bean_test implements Processor{

    private static final String ENDPOINT_NAME = "Endpoint";
    private static final String END_TAG_ENDPOINT_NAME = "endEndpoint";
    private static final int NUMERO_SITE_START_POSITION = 6;
    private static final int NUMERO_SITE_END_POSITION = 11;


    @Override
    public void process(Exchange exchange) throws Exception {

        ProducerTemplate producerTemplate = exchange.getContext().createProducerTemplate();
        String ropEndpoint = exchange.getIn().getHeader(ENDPOINT_NAME, String.class);
        String endRopEndpoint = exchange.getIn().getHeader(END_TAG_ENDPOINT_NAME, String.class);
        InputStream is = new ByteArrayInputStream(exchange.getIn().getBody(String.class).getBytes());
        aggregateBody(producerTemplate, is, ropEndpoint, endRopEndpoint, new HashMap<String, Object>(exchange.getIn().getHeaders()));

    }

    private void aggregateBody(ProducerTemplate producerTemplate, InputStream content, String ropEndPoint, String endRopEndpoint, Map<String, Object> headers){
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(content));
        String line;
        Map<String, StringBuilder> articles = new LinkedHashMap<String, StringBuilder>();
        StringBuilder aggregateFile = new StringBuilder();
        try {
            String lineId = null;
            while((line = br.readLine()) != null){
            lineId = line.substring(NUMERO_SITE_START_POSITION, NUMERO_SITE_END_POSITION);
            }
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        finally{
            try {
                if(br != null)br.close();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Thank you in advance.

Louisa.

EDIT: My new code but i don't know how to return the file.

```
package beans;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.BufferedWriter;
import java.io.ByteArrayInputStream;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileWriter;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Iterator;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.Set;
import java.util.TreeSet;

import org.apache.camel.*;


public class bean_test implements Processor{

    private static final String ENDPOINT = "aggregateEndpoint";
    private static final int NUMERO_SITE_START_POSITION = 46;
    private static final int NUMERO_SITE_END_POSITION = 55;


    @Override
    public void process(Exchange exchange) throws Exception {

        ProducerTemplate producerTemplate = exchange.getContext().createProducerTemplate();
        String endpoint = exchange.getIn().getHeader(ENDPOINT, String.class);
        InputStream is = new ByteArrayInputStream(exchange.getIn().getBody(String.class).getBytes());
        aggregateBody(producerTemplate, is, endpoint, new HashMap<String, Object>(exchange.getIn().getHeaders()));

    }

    private void aggregateBody(ProducerTemplate producerTemplate, InputStream content, String endpoint, Map<String, Object> headers){
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(content));
        String line;
        Set<String> order=new TreeSet<String>();

        try {
            String lineId = null;   
            while((line = br.readLine()) != null){
                lineId = line.substring(NUMERO_SITE_START_POSITION, NUMERO_SITE_END_POSITION);
                order.add(lineId);
            }

            for(int i=0;i<order.size();i++){
                String key = "file" + i;
                File F = new File(key);
                Iterator it = order.iterator();
                FileWriter fw = new FileWriter(F.getAbsoluteFile());
                BufferedWriter bw = new BufferedWriter(fw);

                while((line = br.readLine()) != null){
                    while(it.hasNext()){
                        lineId = line.substring(NUMERO_SITE_START_POSITION, NUMERO_SITE_END_POSITION);
                        if (lineId.equals(it.next())) {
                            bw.write(line);
                        }
                    }

                }
            }


        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        finally{
            try {
                if(br != null)br.close();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What's the logic on splitting the file?

Comment: Hello Boris,
The logic is based on the fields 1855 and 1856 (Position 7 to 11 in my file).
It should be aggregated together in 1855 and 1856 (two files).

Comment: Well just do that. 1) Open two files. 2) `stream()` the lines from the input file. 3) Depending on the field in question, write line to the appropriate file. 4) Close the files.

Comment: Getting back to Boris's question, [why do you need to split files at all](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem) - this is giant red warning light that you're asking about how to implement a solution to the problem you had, instead of asking how to solve the problem, it's almost a given that splitting files is not even remotely the solution here.

Comment: Tell me if I'm correct: Do you want a new file for each order number, and write every line with that order number into its own file?

Comment: Also, what would you want each of your files to be called?

Comment: Hello JD9999, yes I want a new file for each order number, and write every line with that order number into its own file.I want these files are called at the end of my code.

Comment: Is your new program creating the files? Looking at your code, it appears that your output files will be empty, because the second time you try to iterate over your input stream, it is already at the end. What exactly do you want to return (what do you want the body of the message to be AFTER it has gone through this processor? A list of file-names? or something else?  [Also, you can remove your old version from your question.]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This answer is really by user **Ranx**, [from the Camel list](http://camel.465427.n5.nabble.com/Cut-file-td5786003.html), not my own; but, I think it is worth reproducing because it is elegant and maintains the Camel idiom.

**Conceptually**, you want to **split** the records in a file. Then, for each record, you want to use some value to **choose** a destination output-file.
[image]

The Camel-specific solution offered by user **Ranx** on the Camel list used a Camel feature: the destination file name can be derived from a value in the message (which was part of your spec).

[image]
You split into records, then unmarshal the string into some format, pull the required field and set it to the header, marshal it back into a string, and finally write to a file (appending), using the header value in the file name.

This was expressed in the snippet:

```
from("file:/inbox")
 .split(body())
 .unmarshal(dataFormat)
 .setHeader("fileName",simple("${body.identifier}"))
 .marshal(dataFormat)
 .to("file:/outbox/?fileName=${header.fileName}.txt&fileExist=Append")
```

Alternately, you could probably avoid marshalling and unmarshalling, and use a simple Processor which read the String body as-is, and set a header as above. This would be:
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Many seem to think you should not be splitting your files.  But if you have to do this, a simple solution is to read in your file, which I call `flatfile.txt` below, and check the second entry of each line to see if it be `1855` or `1856`.  In each case, then write the output to the appropriate file.

```
try {
    File f1 = new File("f1855.txt");
    File f2 = new File("f1856.txt");

    if (!f1.exists()) {
        f1.createNewFile();
    }
    FileWriter fw1 = new FileWriter(f1.getAbsoluteFile());
    BufferedWriter bw1 = new BufferedWriter(fw1);

    if (!f2.exists()) {
        f2.createNewFile();
    }
    FileWriter fw2 = new FileWriter(f2.getAbsoluteFile());
    BufferedWriter bw2 = new BufferedWriter(fw2);

    String currLine;
    BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("flatfile.txt"));

    while ((currLine = br.readLine()) != null) {
        String[] parts = currLine.split(" ");
        if (parts[1].equals("1855")) {
            bw1.write(currLine);
        }
        else if (parts[1].equals("1856")) {
            bw2.write(currLine);
        }
        else {
            System.out.println("Found a line which did not match 1855 or 1856.");
        }
    }
} catch (IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
} finally {
    try {
        if (br != null) br.close();
        if (bw1 != null) bw1.close();
        if (bw2 != null) bw2.close();
    } catch (IOException ex) {
        ex.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks Tim for you answer !

it's more complicated, I block.
My input file, the code 1855 or 1856 is not always the same, it is an order number and I don't know how many different codes I have in my file. I can have 5, 6, 7 code and files.
Sorry, I misspoke :(

Comment: @Louisa So then are you prepared to have an arbitrary number of output files for each order number?  Now I am beginning to agree that your approach may be incorrect.

Comment: I need a single file by order but I can have a random number order in the original file.
I also think I'm going in the wrong direction...

Comment: Update your question and describe the actual problem you are trying to solve.  You just told me you need a single file, but in the OP you said you wanted two files.

Comment: Sorry Tim, I terribly expressed.
I edited my post, I hope it's clearer....
You are really nice to be interested in my problem.

Comment: You should be able to easily adapt my code to write any number of files per order.

Comment: If you must split into multiple file , perhaps sort the incoming file on that field. Then write to a single output file at a time, changing the destination each time the field value changes.

Comment: Thank you for you help !
I tried to make a new code but it doesn't work. Could you help me? I started in java